# Angular trackBy returning the index in *ngFor vs item id

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a huge ngFor, changing frequently with asynchronous data. TrackBy allows to only refresh the changing part,  and I really feel the difference when I add it.
It seems clear to me what is the benefit to have a trackBy returning a unique ID, for example. 
But I sometime see samples returning the current index.

```
public trackByFn(index, item) { return index }
```

In my table, I don't notice any differences if I directly return 'index' or 'item.id'. Both seems optimize the render (but I maybe didn't catch some bugged border cases).

So, can someone explain me what exactly happen when I return the index?

Comment: try changing the order of the data :)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. So I changed my backend to shuffle the list of items and they are displayed randomly, as expected.

Answer (score 44):

Based on your comment, and my own curiosity, I dug into the angular [differ code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.3/packages/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts).
I can break it down for you what happens in the 3 different scenarios and I suppose it's a nice to have knowledge as well:

**First scenario**:

> No `trackBy` defined: `<div *ngFor="let obj of arrayOfObj">{{obj.key}}</div>`

If there is no `trackBy` defined, angular iterates over the array, creates the DOM elements and binds the data in the template within the `[ngForOf]`. (Above code can be written as):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="arrayOfObj">
  <div>{{obj.key}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

So basically, it creates all those div elements. Initially this is the same for all 3 possibilities. Now new data arrives from the API, more or less the same data, but the reference to the array object changes, and all the references from the objects in the initial array are different. If you do not define a trackBy function, angular compares by identity `===`. This will go well with strings, numbers and other primitives (not that many out there). But for objects, this will not. So what happens now if it starts checking if there are changes. It cannot find the original objects anymore so it removes the DOM elements (actually stores it somewhere for later use, if an object decides to come back), and build all the templates from scratch.

> *Even if the data hasn't changed, the second response produces objects with different identities, and Angular must tear down the entire DOM and rebuild it (as if all old elements were deleted and all new elements inserted)*.

You can imagine that this can be quite cpu hungry, and memory hungry.

**Second scenario**:

> `trackBy` defined with object key:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of arrayOfObj;trackBy:trackByKey">{{obj.key}}</div>

trackByKey = (index: number, obj: object): string => {
  return object.key;
};
```

Let's do this one first. It's the quickest one. So we are at the point where new data comes in, with objects of different identities than before. At this point, angular iterates all new objects over this trackBy function and get the identity of the object. It will than cross reference it to existing (and previously deleted if not found) DOM elements. If found, it will still update any bindings made inside the template. If not found, it will check previously removed objects, and if it still cannot find it, it will create a new DOM element from the template and update the bindings. So, this is quick. Just looking for already created DOM elements, and update bindings, which angular can do quick quick quick.

**Third scenario**:

> `trackBy` defined with array index

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of arrayOfObj;trackBy:trackByIndex">{{obj.key}}</div>

trackByIndex = (index: number): number => {
  return index;
};
```

This is the same story as the trackBy object key, but with the small difference that if you go play juggle with the elements inside the array, the bindings within the templates keep getting updated. But this is still fast, but most likely not the fastest way :), although it's a lot faster than recreating the entire DOM.

Hope you get the difference now. A little something extra though. If you have a lot of business objects which all have the same way to access their identity, like a property `.id` or `.key`, you can extend the native `*ngFor` and create your own structural directive which has this `trackBy` function built in. Untested code though:

```
export interface BaseBo {
  key: string;
}

@Directive({selector: '[boFor][boForOf]'})
export class ForOfDirective<T extends BaseBo> extends NgForOf<T> {
  @Input()
  set boForOf(boForOf: T[]) {
    this.ngForOf = boForOf;
  }

  ngForTrackBy = (index: number, obj: T) => obj.key;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why isn't the third method the fastest one? It will always reuse existing DOM objects, unless the size of our data array changes. So when the object key changes, the second method will recreate its DOM element, but in the track by index case it will just update the bindings in an existing DOM element.

Comment: @user4205580 If the length doesn't change, and you do not reorder the items, then yes, using the index is faster or at least as fast as the object id. But if for instance, removing the first item, will make all remaining items have a different index and will make it slow-ish. I don't know the exact internals, or what the side effects could be when something like this happens. I always just use an object key to be safe. That the same component receives the same data object

Comment: If the length stays the same and I reorder the items in the array, then track by index will not create new DOM elements because the all exist - every index in the array has a matching DOM element. All that happens is the bindings get updated, right? So it will be as fast as the key method. But even when I replace one item with a completely new data in the array, track by index will not create new DOM elements neither, because the array length hasn't changed. I mean, there are scenarios when using index is faster than using key and vice versa.

Comment: By the way, when bindings are updated, does it happen for all data in the array? Or is there any mechanism that helps Angular determine whar should be updated and what doesn't need to be updated?

Comment: @user4205580 Btw, this is all in a `OnPush` strategy, because you should be using that to begin with. Anyways, when you are shuffling elements, all that happens is that angular just moves the actual elements around this does not cost a lot, because the elements already exist, and if no inputs have changed from those elements, nothing really happens but that, but if you shuffle with index, all elements whose index changes, also will have different input values, causing change detection from within those changed *ngFor templates (and any child components)

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense. I thought that Angular performs updates on all elements, but if that's the case, then it's obivously better to track by key.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use index? Let's assume we have an array, then it updates, length doesn't change, but the items inside array are fully different. So, our trackBy returns indexes angular sees that everything is same according to indexes and won't update anything, though the array items are fully changed.

Comment: @OsmanOmar it sort of depends, if you loop over components with an object array and pass in an object to the component (which is the most common use case), the input of the component does change, and will trigger appropriate change detection. However it will trigger too much, because instead of moving the component and not update the input, it will keep the component in place and change the content. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PoulKruijt What if we have only html template instead of component. Will it trigger changeDetection when the data changes? By html template I mean we don't have any @Input() params.

Comment: @OsmanOmar I can't think of a situation where you would loop over elements, and then not use such element in any template binding (even `{{ xxx }}`) would trigger it