# Does angular treat data as different from (http) api request?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

So i am figuring out is there any benefit from using trackByFn
 for *ngFor if data is updating from API request on server. Does Angular see if just part of data updated or it see like absolutely new data, because it from another request ?

Comment: for an explanation I can direct you to another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478273/angular-trackby-returning-the-index/54484184#54484184

Comment: thanks, that what i was searching for.