# Angular button doesn't work within FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying a simple form array a bit like a ToDo list however I am adding a button to each item within the list to allow it to be deleted (though didn't recreate this part within the example).

I am finding that the button for each item is not "clickable". I also noticed that the "ripple" effect doesn't work as it should on those buttons too.

I have managed to create a stackblitz to re-create it so any help would be appreciated

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-ck2jpe

> To use just enter something in to the textbox, click ADD and then try to delete it from the list below where it appeared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you do not add a `trackBy` function to your `*ngFor`. This makes the entire list DOM to be recreated when you do a mousedown, so the `click` never gets triggered, because the element is destroyed.

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-f1wftb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a working example:

```
trackBy(idx: number, item: { id: number }): number {
  return item.id;
}
```

template:

```
<ul formArrayName="items"
    *ngFor="let item of exampleForm.controls.items.value; let i = index;trackBy: trackBy">
```

For more information you can read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478273/angular-trackby-returning-the-index/54484184#54484184) about this subject. Basically what happens is that the `exampleForm.controls.items.value` reference changes with every event that happens.

---

Another solution, could be to use the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component declaration. I recommend you to use both `trackBy` and the `OnPush` for the most performance improvement. Be aware though that this might require some refactoring in your current application code.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-deyyn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Pierre NOT iterate over exampleForm.controls.items. **value**, else `exampleForm.get('items').controls`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - I have implemented your suggestions and now have my solution working - Much appreciated