# Nothing happens when link inside ngFor is clicked

Tags: angular

This code works well:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div>
        <a [routerLink]="'3'" mat-raised-button>Voir la boutique</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Text]

As we can see, it produces a link button with a correct URL and if I click on it, it works well.

But the code below doesn't work. The only difference is the presence of a ngFor loop before the link:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div *ngFor="let storeGroup of groupedStoreList">
        <a [routerLink]="'3'" mat-raised-button>Voir la boutique</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Text]

The previous link button is repeated, which is expected because of the ngFor, and the generated link seems to be OK too when I hover it. **But if I click on it, nothing happens**.

I use Bootstrap and Angular Material, don't know if it can be related or not.

Comment: have you registered a route and a component to that route? see console for errors.

Comment: @AamerShahzad yes I did. As I said in my post, if I remove the ngFor directive, everything works well, meaning that the click makes me navigate to the right route. And I don't have any error in console, once again, as I said in the post, litterally nothing happens when I click the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I can see this happening is if the `mousedown` triggers a change detection, which causes the elements to re-render, and not catching the click anymore. There are some fixes for this, which are in itself best practices.

Use the `OnPush` change detection strategy in all your components:

```
@Component({
  // ...,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
// ...
```

besides that, with an `ngFor` over objects, it also advised to use the `trackBy` option. This will prevent unnecessary rerenders of your DOM:

```
<div *ngFor="let storeGroup of groupedStoreList; trackBy: trackByStoreList">
```

which you needs to declare in your component:

```
trackByStoreList(index: number, storeList: StoreList): string {
  return storeList.id;
}
```

You need to return some unique identifier of your object, if you do not have that, you can use the index. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478273/angular-trackby-returning-the-index-in-ngfor-vs-item-id/54484184#54484184) for more information

Comment: I applied your suggestion about detection strategy and it worked, thanks ! However, I really wonder why this problem occured to me because this is far from being my first Angular project and I haven't seen a similar problem on Stackoverflow...

Comment: @Flobesst It's a relatively common issue with `ngFor` and change detection. Besides performance, it's one of the main reasons to use `trackBy` with all object iterations. Could it be that `groupedStoreList` is a getter in your component? That would make sense that the array and/or object references changes

Comment: Oh you're right, it's a getter. That makes sense now, thank you !